# Using regex to capture a value in a text line

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text line and I need capture the value "Keyword" key.

In this sample the value is "ConquestImageDate".

With my code below I can capture the value as ConquestImageDate".

But it has a '"' on the end.

I know I can use a replace to get rid off  it.

But, I´d like to do it in the regex.

```
let line =
  '(0008,0023) VERS="CQ"   VR="DA"   VM="1"    Keyword="ConquestImageDate"             Name="Conquest Image Date"';
const re = /Keyword=\"\s*(\S+)/;
m = re.exec(line);
console.log(m[1]);
```

Comment: You just have to add quotes at the end? Like `/Keyword=\"\s*(\S+)"/` after the string so the regex knows what to select in the group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not matching the closing `"`, and as exec might yield null you can check for `m` first before indexing into it.

```js
let line =
  '(0008,0023) VERS="CQ"   VR="DA"   VM="1"    Keyword="ConquestImageDate"             Name="Conquest Image Date"';
const re = /Keyword="\s*(\S+)"/;
m = re.exec(line);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

If there can also be unwanted whitespace chars at the end, you could making the `\S` non greedy.

```js
let line =
  '(0008,0023) VERS="CQ"   VR="DA"   VM="1"    Keyword="ConquestImageDate"             Name="Conquest Image Date"';
const re = /Keyword="\s*(\S*?)\s*"/;
m = re.exec(line);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

---

You are matching `Keyword` which is singular, but if in any case you want to match spaces or newlines as well between the double quotes

```
\bKeyword="\s*([^"]*?)"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/05vyWA/1)